# C Structure TriplePointer Memory Allocation

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have this two structures:

```C
typedef struct {
    unsigned int rows;
    unsigned int cols;
    Cell ***cells;
} Board;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int info;  
    unsigned char state;    
    unsigned int mines;
} Cell;
```

initialized the board structure:

```c
board = (Board*) malloc(sizeof(Board));
board->rows = 2;
board->cols = 2;
board->cells = NULL;
```

after that I call this function:

```c
int initCells(Board **board) {
    Cell **cells = (Cell**) malloc((*board)->rows * sizeof(Cell*));

    for (int i = 0; i < (*board)->rows; i++) {
        cells[i] = (Cell*) malloc((*board)->cols * sizeof(Cell));
    }
    (*board)->cells = &cells;

    (*board)->cells[0][0]->info = 7;
    (*board)->cells[0][1]->info = 7;
    (*board)->cells[1][0]->info = 7; // segmentation fault
    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get on the third segmentation fault and what would be the correct way to allocate memory to the triple pointer?

Comment: How does `Cell ***cells` make sense, is it a 3D version of minesweeper or something?

Comment: I suspect you rather want something like `Cell (*cells)[MAX_COLS];` then `board.cells = malloc( sizeof(Cell[rows][cols]) );` ... `free(board.cells)`.

Comment: The `cells` variable in the function is a single pointer and not an array.  So in the assignment, `&cells` is a pointer to a single pointer.  And when you do `(*board)->cells[x]` you are treating it as an array.  You definitely want the board struct to have `Cell **cells;` so that it is a pointer to the memory that got malloced and not to the address of a local variable that points to the malloced memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
(*board)->cells = &cells;
```

This sets the board cells pointer to point to a **local** variable from the function. When the function returns that pointer is no longer valid.

It seems like yo have one pointer level too many. There is no reason I can see for the third level.

Also the second level on the `board` parameter just complicates things, but is is totally superfluous.